# How can I change an inputs background opacity without affecting the text in React Native?

Tags: react-native, styling, opacity

I want to change the opacity of an inputs backgroundColor to 0.5 while keeping the text of the input at 1. When I change the opacity of the background it also changes the text. How do I change only the backgrounds opacity without affecting the text?

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import CalculateDiscount from '../calculate-discount/CalculateDiscount';


const Discount = () => {

   const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
   const [discount, setDiscount] = useState(0);

   return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
           <TextInput style={styles.input}
               placeholder='enter price'
               keyboardType='numeric'
               value={price}
               onChangeText={(value) => setPrice(value)}
           />
           <TextInput style={styles.input}
               placeholder='enter discount %'
               keyboardType='numeric'
               value={discount}
               onChangeText={(value) => setDiscount(value)}
           />

           <CalculateDiscount price={price} discount={discount}/>
       </View>
   )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
       height: '100%',
       backgroundColor: '#F1F6FA',
   },

   input: {
       width: '90%',
       alignSelf: 'center',
       marginTop: 20,
       height: 80,
       borderRadius: 30,
       borderWidth: 1,
       textAlign: 'center',
       backgroundColor: '#90B0DD',
       fontSize: 26,
       fontWeight: 'bold',
       
   },

})

export default Discount;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your existing hexadecimal colour, to take advantage of the contemporary availability of transparency, from:

```
#rrggbb
```

to:

```
#rrggbbaa
```

In your case we'd amend:

```
backgroundColor: '#90B0DD'
```

to, as an example:

```
backgroundColor: '#90B077';
```

```css
table {
  caption-side: bottom;
  inline-size: clamp(30rem, 60%, 1000px);
  margin-inline: auto;
}

caption {
  background-color: #ffa8;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
}

td:first-child {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>
    Note that as the opacity of the color increases (from 00 to ff) in line with the number
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hex color code:</th>
      <th>resulting color:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000000</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000011</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.067);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000022</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.133);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000033</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000044</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.267);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000055</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.333);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000066</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000077</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.467);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000088</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.533);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff000099</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff0000aa</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.667);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff0000bb</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.733);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff0000cc</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff0000dd</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.867);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff0000ee</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.933);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>#ff0000ff</td>
      <td style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use rgba(red, Green, blue, alpha):**

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(144,176,221,0.5)'
```

You can adjust the opacity/alpha by tweaking last parameter passed to rgba method.

Comment: As an aside, it's also possible to utilise the alpha channel in the regular `rgb()` function, using [Color Module 4 syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#color-syntax); to rewrite your posted suggestion that would look like: `rgb(144 176 221 / 0.5)`. :)

Comment: rgb, rgba does not seem to work with react native. However I was able to add a 2 digit number to the end of of the color code to change the opacity as shown above.

Comment: Happy to know you found a solution. But check this [expo snack example](https://snack.expo.dev/gi08WiXhQ) idk why it did not work for you but rgba works in react native.

Comment: I must have typed something wrong when I tried it. Good to know that rgba works also.